# Jersey @InjectLink is not working with a custom JSON entity provider

Tags: java, json, jersey, gson, jersey-2.0

I'm implementing a JSON entity provider for Jersey that uses Gson API,
below is the important method from the provider I wrote"

```
    @Override
    public void writeTo(Object object, Class<?> type, Type genericType, Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType, MultivaluedMap<String, Object> httpHeaders, OutputStream entityStream)
        throws IOException, WebApplicationException {
      OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(entityStream, UTF_8);
      try {
          Object bean = getResponseBean(object);
          gson.toJson(bean, bean.getClass(), writer);
      } finally {
          writer.close();
      }
    }
```

The problem that I'm facing now is that injected links "using @InjectLink annotation" are not working anymore, they are completely ignored!

```
@InjectLink("/Link/...")
@XmlElement(name = "documentURI")
String documentURI;
```

Comment: Was it working before? Have you registered `DeclarativeLinkingFeature`?

Comment: Yes, the moment I turn on my custom entity provider, it stops working..